# Using BuddyPress template tags outside of buddypress only pages

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I am trying to use Buddypress template tags (for example, the compose message form etc.) outside of BuddyPress. I have read that BP_Nav renders a piece of code that it relies on or additionally, that only depending on specific page slugs do specific modules work. I haven't been able to wrap my head around it and would really appreciate some help. I basically want to know what code I need to include to be able to do Buddypress templates with actions (like sending messages etc.) from anywhere on my WordPress install, not just in the BuddyPress specific pages.